# Selenium Python Over lay form and find by Xpath and send value

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Using Selenium Python:
I have an overlay form which has an email text form. I am using the following code to get to overlay form (works fine) and then recognize the email address text box, but is not filling in the value that I desire to fill in the email text box. here is the code I am using.

```
browser.switch_to_frame('loginModel')
browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//*[@id='loginboxif']h1").send_keys('abcd@rediffmail.com')
```

Which is giving the error

```
 line 10, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginboxif']/h1").send_keys('abcd@rediffmail.com')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 221, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
```

Comment: I also tried the following, but again error out:browser.find_element_by_class_name('input-text email required').send_keys('abcd@rediffmail.com'). It gave the error asrowser.find_element_by_class_name('input-text email required').send_keys('mailme.test3@rediffmail.com')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 341, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 681, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']

Comment: Please post the complete error and also the html for the email address textbox.

Comment: Error as :- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Off5th_Registration", line 25, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('input-text email required').send_keys('abcd@rediffmail.com')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 341, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 681, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
 \

Comment: HTML for the email address as    <div class="form-row required ">
<input id="dwfrm_login_username" class="input-text email required" type="text" maxlength="2147483647" value="" name="dwfrm_login_username"/>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont find 'h1' in the html you posted. Then why are you referring that in xpath.

You could simply do the following:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('dwfrm_login_username').send_keys('abcd@rediffmail.com')
```

or

```
browser.find_element_by_name('dwfrm_login_username).send_keys('abcd@rediffmail.com')
```

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[@id='loginboxif']h1
```

is not a valid XPath query. This is your problem. Depending on what you are trying to do, you may want:

```
//*[@id='loginboxif']//h1
```

Similarly:

```
find_element_by_class_name('input-text email required')
```

Compound class names are not allowed.